# NoSuchMethodError:The getter 'document' was called on null?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Hello I am using flutter and  querySnapshot in my code with document but i dont understand whats error anyone help me how i fix this error below my code .......................................................................................................................................................................... **

dd.dart

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchPageState createState() => _SearchPageState();
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SearchPage> {
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  Future<QuerySnapshot> futureSearchResults;
  emptyTheTextFormField() {
    searchTextEditingController.clear();
  }

  controllSearching(String str) {
    Future<QuerySnapshot> allUsers = userRefrence
        .where("profileName", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: str)
        .getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      futureSearchResults = allUsers;
    });
  }

  Container displayNoSearchResult() {
    final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.group,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 200.0,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 20.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Search Users",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 65.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  displayUsersFoundScreen() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureSearchResults,
      builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<UserResult> searchUserResult = [];
        dataSnapshot.data.document.forEach((document) {
          User eachuser = User.fromDocument(document);
          UserResult userResult = UserResult(eachuser);
          searchUserResult.add(userResult);
        });
        return ListView(children: searchUserResult);
      },
    );
  }

  AppBar searchPageHeader() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      title: TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white),
        controller: searchTextEditingController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Search Here....",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          filled: true,
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_pin, color: Colors.white, size: 30.0),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.clear,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: emptyTheTextFormField),
        ),
        onFieldSubmitted: controllSearching,
      ),
    );
  }

  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: searchPageHeader(),
      body: futureSearchResults == null
          ? displayNoSearchResult()
          : displayUsersFoundScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class UserResult extends StatelessWidget {
  final User eachuser;

  UserResult(this.eachuser);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.white54,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => print("tapped"),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(eachuser.url),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    eachuser.profileName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    eachuser.username,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 13.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because of your `if` condition, it should be `if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {...}`.

Replace:

`if (dataSnapshot.hasData) {...}`

with

`if (!dataSnapshot.hasData){...}`.

I added a fix using your code:

```dart
displayUsersFoundScreen() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: futureSearchResults,
      builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) { // should be !dataSnapshot.hasData
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<UserResult> searchUserResult = [];
        dataSnapshot.data.document.forEach((document) {
          User eachuser = User.fromDocument(document);
          UserResult userResult = UserResult(eachuser);
          searchUserResult.add(userResult);
        });
        return ListView(children: searchUserResult);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: its worked but occure nosuchmethodError:class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance  getter 'document'

Comment: Please don't edit your original post to ask another question, Instead, create another question separately.

Comment: can you tell me solution comment problem